# How to access the camera on ESP32 WROVER?

Tags: camera, esp32

I am trying to use Micropython code to capture an image from the OV2640 camera that connects to the WROVER via ribbon cable.  I have tried a number of different custom Micropython interpreters with a camera function for this device but they all failed trying to initiate the camera.  So now I am attempting to drive it directly by writing to the OV2640 registers but cannot connect to it using I2C. From the documentation it seems the I2C data pin is GPIO26 and the clock is GPIO27.  I ran this code to try to detect the camera but it did not find anything

```
import machine
sdaPIN=machine.Pin(26)  
sclPIN=machine.Pin(27)             
i2c=machine.I2C(0,sda=sdaPIN, scl=sclPIN, freq=400000)
devices = i2c.scan()
if len(devices) == 0:
    print("no devices found")
else:
    for device in devices:
        print("i2C Address: ",hex(device))
```

I also using pins 4 and 5 as but still no results.

That leaves me with the possibility camera is faulty or the cable is not correctly seated (I have re-seated several times) or there is some other trick like a chip select or other pin I don't know about.

Anyone know the answer?